# MovetoThread problems with custom Qobject

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

i am new with QThreads. And didn't understand why i get no new Thread Id for my class. But first a few basic about my problem.

I have a normal c++ class which need a long time to compute lets name her HeavyBaseClass. In this class i have no QT elements.

My goal is to compute this class in her own thread so that the GUI can run normal when she is computing.

I read a few implementation for Qt threading problem and I decided to use QTthread with an QObject. Becuase it should be possible to stop the thread and with my first try QtConcurrent this was not possible.

Because that i created my own QObject:
h.file:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <HeavyBaseClass.h>
class Qoptimization : public QObject , HeavyBaseClass
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Qoptimization(HeavyBaseClass INPUT PARAMETER,QObject *parent = 0);
    void debugThread();
signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // QOPTIMIZATION_H
```

cpp file:

```
#include "qoptimization.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
Qoptimization::Qoptimization(HeavyBaseClass INPUT PARAMETER, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),HeavyBaseClass (INPUT PARAMETER)
{
    qDebug() << " init Thread " <<   this->thread()->currentThreadId() ;
}

void Qoptimization::debugThread(){
    qDebug() << " current Thread " <<   thread()->currentThreadId() ;
}
```

now i call this on my mainwindow

```
qDebug() << " Main Thread " <<   this->thread()->currentThreadId();
Qoptimization qoptimization(f);
QThread *optimizationThread = new QThread();
qDebug() << " before moving to Thread " <<   qoptimization.thread()->currentThreadId();
qoptimization.moveToThread(optimizationThread);
optimizationThread->start();
qoptimization.debugThread();
qDebug() << " after moving Thread " <<   qoptimization.thread()->currentThreadId();
```

the problem which i dont understand is that my thead id is the same on alle outputs.

DEBUG Information:

```
 Main Thread  0xd88 
 init Thread  0xd88 
 before moving to Thread  0xd88 
 current Thread  0xd88 
 after moving Thread  0xd88
```

Do you have an idea what I did wrong ?

---

UPDATE:

new cpp

```
void Qoptimization::debugThread(){
    qDebug() << " in debugThred currentThread() " <<   QThread::currentThread() ;
    qDebug() << " in debugThread Thread " <<   thread() ;

    if ( QThread::currentThread() != thread() )
     {
         // Force slot to be emmited in object thread
         QTimer::singleShot( 0, this, SLOT( debugThread() ) );
         return ;
     }
}
```

Output:

```
 Main Thread  0x156c 
 init Thread  0x156c 
 before moving to Thread  0x156c 
 in debugThred currentThread()  QThread(0xeccc00) 
 in debugThread Thread  QThread(0x24cad80) 
 after moving Thread  0x156c
```

Comment: if `HeavyBaseClass` is so heavy why not use composition instead of inheritance??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation [currentThreadId](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qthread.html#currentThreadId) is STATIC member of QThread, so you always print callers thread id. So you should print `(quint64)qoptimization.thread()` member of object.

If you want your member `void debugThread();` to be executed in another thread - you should declare it as a SLOT and do not call directrly. You should call it throught connected signals, object metadata or timers. Try next code:

```
public slots:
    void Qoptimization::debugThread();

void Qoptimization::debugThread()
{
    if ( QThread::currentThread() != thread() )
    {
        // Force slot to be emmited in object thread
        QTimer::singleShot( 0, this, SLOT( debugThread() ) );
        return ;
    }

    qDebug() << " current Thread " <<   thread()->currentThreadId() ;
}
```

[Qt documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qthread.html) has good samples. But first, you should understand [Qt signal/slot](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) system.

------- Pseudocode for comment:

```
class MyClass
{
  int thread() const { return m_id; }
  void moveToThread( int threadid ) { m_id = threadid; }
  int m_id;
}

MyClass a;
const int curThread = 1;
a.moveToThread( 2 );
qDebug() << curThread << " " << a.thread();
// output: 1 2 // already different!
```

Comment: Hello, first thank you for your help. I get some think really funny which i dont really understand I did two new outputs on my debugThread function. But on the first call i already have different threads ... So it never jumps in the if loop. I updated my post above

Comment: It's OK on first call. `QThread::currentThread()` - is CURRENT CALLER THREAD. `thread()` - is THREAD WHERE SLOTS ARE CALLED BY EVENTS. Your mistake is that you didn't declare `debugThread()` as slot. So it couldn't be called by QTimer. I highlighted it in first line of code. Try to read Qt output in debugger console. It will show runtime warnings.

Comment: it is defined as SLOT. When i run debugThread() the first time i already have different threads. But i dont really understand why.

Comment: Because on your first call of `debugThread()` your object already moved to `optimizationThread`. What exact you dont understand? I added pseudo-code to my answer.

Comment: i have only one time the output of debugThread but i call it 2 times. Onetime as function and then i recall inside the function or? But if i used the debuger i get inside if loop so everythink is fine thank you

Comment: Because you start thread after first call. You should do call only after "started()" signal is emitted. When QThread event loop will be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

When you move an object to a thread it doesnt mean calling this object methods will magically be executed in the thread.

```
qoptimization.debugThread();
```

Is still executing in the caller thread, and that's how it should be. To execute in `optimizationThread` you need to use signals and slots to trigger function executions.